# rsync で '-c' オプション使用時、チェックサムが同じでもコピーが実行されてしまう

Tags: rsync

rsyncでローカルのファイルをリモートサーバーに転送しようとしています。
この際、ローカルのファイルの更新日時は無視して、チェックサムだけでコピーが必要なファイルかどうかを判定したいと思い、`-c` (`--checksum`) オプションを利用しています。

しかし、チェックサムが同じにもかかわらず、コピーが実施されてしまいます。
このようなことが起きる原因として、どのようなことが考えられるでしょうか。

なお、rsyncは、下記のようなコマンドを実行しています。

```
rsync -crlptzhv --delete -e <SSH接続情報> ./public/ example@remote_host:/home/example/public_html/example.com/
```

環境は、Ubuntu20.04、rsync 3.2.3です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「チェックサムが同じ」というのはどの様にして確認したのでしょう？ rsync の場合、v3.0.0 以降では checksum に MD5 を利用していますが(オプションで変更可能)、md5sum コマンドなどを使って確認したのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、md5sumで確認しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ローカルのファイルのタイムスタンプが変更されているため、それを反映する必要があったようです。
下記のように `-t` オプションを外すことで、期待通りに動作しました。

```
rsync -crlpzhv --delete -e <SSH接続情報> ./public/ example@remote_host:/home/example/public_html/example.com/
```